# Passing message from Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment, android-fragmentactivity

I seem to have a problem passing data gotten in an Activity to a Fragment. The data does not appear in the listfragment!
Here is my listfragmentactivity. I reinstantiate the fragment every time I add an item to the list aka bundle an item and use the constructor in the new fragment to do it.

```
package com.example.sample;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

/**
 * An activity representing a list of Courses. This activity has different
 * presentations for handset and tablet-size devices. On handsets, the activity
 * presents a list of items, which when touched, lead to a
 * {@link CourseDetailActivity} representing item details. On tablets, the
 * activity presents the list of items and item details side-by-side using two
 * vertical panes.
 * <p>
 * The activity makes heavy use of fragments. The list of items is a
 * {@link CourseListFragment} and the item details (if present) is a
 * {@link CourseDetailFragment}.
 * <p>
 * This activity also implements the required
 * {@link CourseListFragment.Callbacks} interface to listen for item selections.
 */
public class CourseListActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements
    CourseListFragment.Callbacks {

CourseListFragment listFrag;

public static String courseName;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 10;

/**
 * Whether or not the activity is in two-pane mode, i.e. running on a tablet
 * device.
 */
private boolean mTwoPane;
private boolean once = true;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_course_list);

    if (findViewById(R.id.course_detail_container) != null) {
        // The detail container view will be present only in the
        // large-screen layouts (res/values-large and
        // res/values-sw600dp). If this view is present, then the
        // activity should be in two-pane mode.
        mTwoPane = true;

        // In two-pane mode, list items should be given the
        // 'activated' state when touched.
        listFrag = ((CourseListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.course_list));
        listFrag.setActivateOnItemClick(true);
    }

    // TODO: If exposing deep links into your app, handle intents here.
}

/**
 * Callback method from {@link CourseListFragment.Callbacks} indicating that
 * the item with the given ID was selected.
 */

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    boolean bool;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.add_course:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CourseAddActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        bool = true;
    default:
        bool = super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return bool;
}

@Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
      if (data.hasExtra("courseName")) {
        courseName = data.getExtras().getString("courseName");
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("courseKey", courseName);
        listFrag = new CourseListFragment(args);
      }
    }
  }

@Override
public void onItemSelected(String id) {
    if (mTwoPane) {
        // In two-pane mode, show the detail view in this activity by
        // adding or replacing the detail fragment using a
        // fragment transaction.
        if (once) {
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
            // initiating both tabs and set text to it.
            ActionBar.Tab assignTab = actionBar.newTab().setText(
                    "Assignments");
            ActionBar.Tab schedTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Schedule");
            ActionBar.Tab contactTab = actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText("Contact");

            // Create three fragments to display content
            Fragment assignFragment = new Assignments();
            Fragment schedFragment = new Schedule();
            Fragment contactFragment = new Contact();

            assignTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(assignFragment));
            schedTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(schedFragment));
            contactTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(contactFragment));

            actionBar.addTab(assignTab);
            actionBar.addTab(schedTab);
            actionBar.addTab(contactTab);
            once = false;
        }
    } else {
        // In single-pane mode, simply start the detail activity
        // for the selected item ID.
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, CourseDetailActivity.class);
        startActivity(detailIntent);
    }

}

class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    public Fragment fragment;

    public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.replace(R.id.course_detail_container, fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.remove(fragment);
    }
}
}
```

And here is my ListFragment, where I create two constructors, one which accepts arguments.

```
package com.example.sample;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment;

/**
 * A list fragment representing a list of Courses. This fragment also supports
 * tablet devices by allowing list items to be given an 'activated' state upon
 * selection. This helps indicate which item is currently being viewed in a
 * {@link CourseDetailFragment}.
 * <p>
 * Activities containing this fragment MUST implement the {@link Callbacks}
 * interface.
 */
public class CourseListFragment extends SherlockListFragment {

private static String courseName;
ArrayList<String> courseItems;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
/**
 * The serialization (saved instance state) Bundle key representing the
 * activated item position. Only used on tablets.
 */
private static final String STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION = "activated_position";

/**
 * The fragment's current callback object, which is notified of list item
 * clicks.
 */
private Callbacks mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;

/**
 * The current activated item position. Only used on tablets.
 */
private int mActivatedPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;

/**
 * A callback interface that all activities containing this fragment must
 * implement. This mechanism allows activities to be notified of item
 * selections.
 */
public interface Callbacks {
    /**
     * Callback for when an item has been selected.
     */
    public void onItemSelected(String id);
}

/**
 * A dummy implementation of the {@link Callbacks} interface that does
 * nothing. Used only when this fragment is not attached to an activity.
 */
private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(String id) {
    }
};

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public CourseListFragment() {
}

public CourseListFragment(Bundle args) {
    courseName = args.get("courseKey").toString();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    courseItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, courseItems);
    // TODO: replace with a real list adapter.
    int layout = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) ? android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1
            : android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    // Restore the previously serialized activated item position.
    if (savedInstanceState != null
            && savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION)) {
        setActivatedPosition(savedInstanceState
                .getInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION));
        courseItems.add(courseName);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // Activities containing this fragment must implement its callbacks.
    if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.");
    }

    mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    // Reset the active callbacks interface to the dummy implementation.
    mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);

    // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
    // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (mActivatedPosition != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        // Serialize and persist the activated item position.
        outState.putInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION, mActivatedPosition);
    }
}

/**
 * Turns on activate-on-click mode. When this mode is on, list items will be
 * given the 'activated' state when touched.
 */
public void setActivateOnItemClick(boolean activateOnItemClick) {
    // When setting CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE, ListView will automatically
    // give items the 'activated' state when touched.
    getListView().setChoiceMode(
            activateOnItemClick ? ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE
                    : ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
}

private void setActivatedPosition(int position) {
    if (position == ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        getListView().setItemChecked(mActivatedPosition, false);
    } else {
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
    }

    mActivatedPosition = position;
}
}
```

Any help at all is much appreciated!
Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you re-instantiate like this, class variables of `CourseListFragment` will be destroyed each time you call

`listFrag = new CourseListFragment(args);`

You should create a method in `CourseListFragment` to add a course name without destroying the current fragment:

```
public void addCourse(String courseName) {
    courseItems.add(courseName);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And in your activity:

```
@Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
      if (data.hasExtra("courseName")) {
        courseName = data.getExtras().getString("courseName");
        listFrag.addCourse(courseName);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your solution worked! So I'm guessing that when sending arguments from Activity to fragment, define adding methods in the fragment and when sending arguments from the fragment to the activity, define an interface that the activity can implement.

Comment: @aindurti You are welcome:) In general you may think in this way: if you need to constantly update a fragment without destroying it, you need to define methods for that, otherwise using `setArguments()` alone should be enough; if your fragment needs to communicate with the parent activity, as you said, implementing an interface is the way to go.